# Split video "window" during playback

Tags: linux, video

How can I split a video window like this?

[image]

First image is the original video. Second image is me defining the split (not necessarily in a graphical way). Third image is what I'd like to obtain, that is two portions of each frame of the video playing in different parts of the screen/window/panel/whatever, with the possibility to zoom-in/out each part.

I can kind of simulate it by running two different synchronized instances of VLC playing the same video, each with a crop filter configured to cut out the other half.

Note:

- I don't want to have to re-encode the video, it should work like the VLC filter, directly on the playback
- It would be great if it could run on Linux (either natively or through wine)
- The more control I have on each splitted part the better it is, but the bare minimum is being able to do a vertical split in the middle and zoom-out both parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VLC:

1. Tools
2. Effects and Filters
3. Video Effects
4. Geometry
5. Wall (1 row, 2 columns)

[image: Screenshot]

Example result:

[image: Example result]